# WSAGetLastError() returns 122

Tags: c++, winsock, getaddrinfo

Well.. I am not really sure what that means, but my systems runs and runs and runs without crying for insufficient memeory...

I guess it has to do with the system error 122, because there is no 122 in the winsock error codes (MSDN)...

Anyone got a clue?...

It occures on a call to `getaddrinfo(NULL, /*PortNumber*/, &hints, &pFinal)`

**EDIT** alright... heres more code (having it not commented out, doesn´t make sense, too)

```
            addrinfo hints, *pFinal = nullptr;
            memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
            hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
            hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
            hints.ai_family = AF_INET;

            if(getaddrinfo(NULL, g_ACCEPTOR_PORT_NUMBER, &hints, &pFinal))
                return ERROR_BIND_SOCKET;
```

The Problem lies in my g_ACCEPTOR_PORT_NUMBER, which is a class containing

```
operator const char*()
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << m_nPortNumber;
        return ss.str().c_str();
    }
```

do I have to change the conversion operator?... I´d prefer to use this "STRINGINT" so i dont need to save the port number as string and number or convert it explicitly...

Comment: Post better code, having PortNumber commented out makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your implementation of `operator const char*()`. Once that function returns, your `stringstream` object is no longer valid because it is no longer in scope.

Answer (score 2):

Probably a bad parameter on the `getaddrinfo` call.  Can you post more code?

Type in `net helpmsg 122` at a command prompt and you get:

> The data area passed to a system call
>   is too small.

Comment: Have that operator return a `std::string` so the data does not go out of scope when `ss.str()` gets destructed

Comment: the problem is, that getaddrinfo takes a const char* and not a str... i try not to use c_str()... but i guess that i have to^^...

Comment: If you want to encapsulate the port in that way, you are going to have to allow getting of its string equivalent in some way.  Returning a `string` and then passing `.c_str()` to the WIn32 API does not seem too messy, does it?  The Win32 APIs are C-oriented so some compromises are inevitable.

Answer (score 1):

`getaddrinfo` actually returns an error code, which you should test against the values specified in the [getaddrinfo documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738520%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

More than likely, the size of the pFinal variable is too small.  You'll need to post more code to get a more thorough answer.

Comment: If it would be, then Microsoft´s programmers had done some incredibly wrong...
Did You even read the code and my comments below the EDIT?=